# Android Studio ic_launcher not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

after have created an icon for the app, android studio is avoiding it when I generate the apk file for release.

```
   error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.elrestaurante:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
    
    error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.example.elrestaurante:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found
```

My project has a git repo. Something rare happens when I do click over each file generated inside mipmap (this disappear), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1JH-5Y7Q9Y) you can see the issue. is a git repo conflict?

Here are the files:

[image]

I generated the icon from file->new->Image Asset.. and also I tested creating the icon doing right click over the res folder then new->Image Asset.

I will appreciate any idea to fix this problem.
thanks so much,

Answer (score 1):

Check your folder structure where the files are located. As it shows debug, check whether there is debug and main in src folder.

Comment: We need to create the icon for main forder and debug. fixed

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you can delete `mipmap` and and `ic_launcher` directory, and then add the Image Asset again, that's what I've always been doing, cause for whatever reason if you add an image asset and another one exist, the previous one is not removed sometimes

Comment: I did this, I remove all the content of this directory and the problem remains. Dont think you that this a problem with git repository?

Answer (score -1):

**Try This**

you are put all icons in debug folder remove them from debug folder and put them outside

debug folder assets only work when you are app running in debug bug release time it's getting errors because the app can't find assets

folder structure like this shown in the below image

[image]